# How to merge two dataframes without generating extra rows in result?

Tags: python, pandas

I am doing the following with two dataframes but it generates duplicates and does not get sorted as the first dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd

dict1 = {
    "time": ["15:09.123", "15:09.234", "15:10.123", "15:11.123", "15:12.123", "15:12.987"],
    "value": [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60]
}

dict2 = {
    "time": ["15:09", "15:09", "15:10"],
    "counts": ["fg", "mn", "gl"],
    "growth": [1, 3, 6]
}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(dict1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(dict2)

df1["time"] = df1["time"].str[:-4]

result = pd.merge(df1, df2, on="time", how="left")
```

This generates the result of 8 rows! I am removing 3 digits from time column in `df1` to match the time in `df2`.

```
    time  value counts  growth
0  15:09     10     fg     1.0
1  15:09     10     mn     3.0
2  15:09     20     fg     1.0
3  15:09     20     mn     3.0
4  15:10     30     gl     6.0
5  15:11     40    NaN     NaN
6  15:12     50    NaN     NaN
7  15:12     60    NaN     NaN
```

There are duplicated columns due to join.

Is it possible to join the dataframes based on `time` column in `df1` where events are sorted well with more time granularity? Is there a way to partially match the `time` column values of two dataframes and merge? Ideal result would look like the following

```
   time       value  counts  growth
0  15:09.123   10     fg     1.0
1  15:09.234   20     mn     3.0
2  15:10.123   30     gl     6.0
3  15:11.123   40     NaN    NaN
4  15:12.123   50     NaN    NaN
5  15:12.987   60     NaN    NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Merge on column 'time' with preserved order
Assumption: Data from df1 and df2 are in order of occurrence

```
import pandas as pd

dict1 = {
    "time": ["15:09.123", "15:09.234", "15:10.123", "15:11.123", "15:12.123", "15:12.987"],
    "value": [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60]
}

dict2 = {
    "time": ["15:09", "15:09", "15:11"],
    "counts": ["fg", "mn", "gl"],
    "growth": [1, 3, 6]
}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(dict1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(dict2)

df1["time"] = df1["time"].str[:-4]

df1_keys = df1["time"].unique()
df_list = list()
for key in df1_keys:
    tmp_df1 = df1[df1["time"] == key]
    tmp_df1 = tmp_df1.reset_index(drop=True)
    tmp_df2 = df2[df2["time"] == key]
    tmp_df2 = tmp_df2.reset_index(drop=True)
    df_list.append(pd.merge(tmp_df1, tmp_df2, left_index=True, right_index=True, how="left"))

print(pd.concat(df_list, axis = 0))
```

Comment: You can't go off the index. The OP has provided sample data. What you give would have to work on millions of rows of data.

Comment: @stefan_aus_hannover thanks for that ^^ edited post with your suggestion and added a test case (df2) in which that change can be seen

Answer (score 0):

here is one way to do it

**Assusmption**: number of rows for a time without seconds in df1 and df2 will be same

```
# create time without seconds
df1['time2']=df1['time'].str[:-4]

# add a sequence when there are multiple rows for any time
df1['seq']=df1.groupby('time2')['time2'].cumcount()

# add a sequence when there are multiple rows for any time
df2['seq']=df2.groupby('time').cumcount()

# do a merge on time (stripped) in df1 and sequence
pd.merge(df1, 
         df2,
        left_on=['time2', 'seq'],
        right_on=['time','seq'],
        how='left',
        suffixes=(None,'_y')).drop(columns=['time2', 'seq'])
```

```
    time     value  time_y  counts  growth
0   15:09.123   10  15:09   fg      1.0
1   15:09.234   20  15:09   mn      3.0
2   15:10.123   30  15:10   gl      6.0
3   15:11.123   40  NaN     NaN     NaN
4   15:12.123   50  NaN     NaN     NaN
5   15:12.987   60  NaN     NaN     NaN
```